# Create an appref-ms file programmatically?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a click once deployed application.
The shortcut that gets created someNAme.appref-ms file has the following contents:

**EFileShare.applicationFileShare.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c9854348sdsdsda82f2074b, processorArchitecture=x86**

Can we create our own appref-ms file with the same content programattically?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was useful:

http://mheironimus.blogspot.com/2009/12/programmatically-create-clickonce.html